# RDM6300 library not working on ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, softwareserial, rfid

I have a [RDM6300](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61XYAIQVh6L._AC_SY355_.jpg) RFID module which I am trying to connect to an [ESP8266](https://www.elektor.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1404d1bfd8e1ad71cc6f16950ff5c805/1/6/169034-91f-web.jpg) by using [rdm6300.h](https://github.com/arduino12/rdm6300) library.

I had it all up an running all along with other components but we had connected to the ESP8266 but we had to move from the breadboard to an actual wired setup. Everything kept on working except for the RFID reader. The way I used to do it was by making a reference to [this](https://github.com/arduino12/rdm6300/blob/master/examples/read_to_serial/read_to_serial.ino) approach (more or less):

```
#include <rdm6300.h>

#define RDM6300_RX_PIN 4
#define READ_LED_PIN 13

Rdm6300 rdm6300;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);

    pinMode(READ_LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(READ_LED_PIN, LOW);

    rdm6300.begin(RDM6300_RX_PIN);

    Serial.println("\nPlace RFID tag near the rdm6300...");
}

void loop()
{
    /* if non-zero tag_id, update() returns true- a new tag is near! */
    if (rdm6300.update())
        Serial.println(rdm6300.get_tag_id(), HEX);

    digitalWrite(READ_LED_PIN, rdm6300.is_tag_near());

    delay(10);
}
```

but now, after the re-arrangement it just stopped reading tags. What I did was to disconnect everything from the ESP and leave only the RDM6300 connected to it with the sample code. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to detect any tags.

In order to test if the components are failing for some reason, I decided to test it by using **SoftwareSerial.h** library on it like this:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial RFID(2, 3); // RX and TX

int i;

void setup()
{
  RFID.begin(9600);    // start serial to RFID reader
  Serial.begin(9600);  // start serial to PC 
}

void loop()
{
  if (RFID.available() > 0) 
  {
     i = RFID.read();
     Serial.print(i, DEC);
     Serial.print(" ");
  }
}
```

and it worked perfectly fine. I was able to read the payload coming from the chip:

> 2 30 31 30 46 33 46 38 44 39 31 32 44 3

But, since I don't want to implement everything related to decoding this serial stream I decided to ask for your opinion what could be wrong here. It used to work without any problem but now it doesn't.

There is something interesting which I also noticed. When I run the first code snipped and change the ESP8266 pin used from 4 to 16(D0) and I upload it, once I move the tag close to the antenna [the hardware light related to this pin](https://lowvoltage.github.io/images/NodeMCU-ESP8266-LEDs.jpg) starts flashing and when I bring the tag back (away from the antenna) it stops flashing.

This makes me thing that on a hardware level everything is fine but some software issues are happening.

Comment: a note to sw Serial sketch: pin 3 is hardware Serial RX

Comment: doesn't the rdm6300 library implement something like sw Serial? did you try sw Serial with pin 4 and rdm6300 with pin 2?

Comment: @Juraj this is the implementation: https://github.com/arduino12/rdm6300/blob/master/src/rdm6300.cpp

Comment: yes, it is a built-in sw Serial

Comment: @Juraj How does that help in my case?

Comment: did you try sw Serial with pin 4 and rdm6300 with pin 2?

Comment: I am using a single pin when making the connection between ESP8266 and RDM6300. It could be any digital pin.

Comment: yes but pin 2 works with SoftwareSerial. did you try it with RDM6300 library?

Comment: Yes, I did it that is the problem that it used to work now it doesn't. I have described it in my question.

Comment: in question you write about 4 and 16 with RDM6300 library.  and you write pin 2 works with SoftwareSerial. so did you try `rdm6300.begin(2);`?

Comment: I have tried that and GPIO2 led on board flashes when tag is near by, but `rdm6300.update()` never returns true. So, I can not detect the actual tag and read its ID. This is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed the issue for me was to go to Boards manager on Arduino IDE and update to latest version:

[image]

Then I got the following error when compiling:

> Board generic (platform esp8266, package esp8266) is unknown

In order to fix that, I followed [these](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/a04-board-generic-is-unknown.html#how-to-resolve-board-generic-platform-esp8266-package-esp8266-is-unknown-error) instructions.

And, I also removed rdm6300 library from **C:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries** and moved it in **C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Arduino\libraries**